# Endless loop with std::distance on custom list

Tags: c++, iterator

For the fun of it, I implemented a `std::list` similar container by myself.

I will never use it in reality. Just practising . . .

During the comparison of my implemented functionality with the `std::list`, I found a severe problem.

Testing `std::distance` with invalid parameters, as part of a simple unit test, shows different results.

Of course I expect UB and indeterminate results, but `std::distance` on my implementation goes into an endless loop, while it does not with a `std::list`. Why?

**Why is my implementation causing an endles loop with `std::distance`?**

I followd [link1](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/d9375e490072d1aae73a93949aa158fcd2a27018/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h#L135) and [link2](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/a12cb9d211019d99b5875b6d8034617cbc24c2cc/include/iterator#L611) in CPP reference to the source code of [std::distance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) and tried to reproduce it. But this works also for my implemenation.

Test/driver code:

```
int main() {

    // std::list works. No endless loop. 
    std::list<int> list1{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::cout << std::distance(list1.end(), list1.begin()) << '\n';

    // Custom list
    List<int> list2{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    // Delta works
    std::cout << list2.begin() - list2.end() << '\n'; 
    std::cout << list2.end() - list2.begin() << '\n';

    // Hopp Count works
    List<int>::iterator i = list2.end();
    int counter = 0;
    while (i != list2.end()) { 
        ++counter;
        ++i;
    }
    std::cout << counter << '\n';

    // Distance will go into endless loop ****************************
    std::cout << std::distance(list2.end(), list2.begin()) << '\n';
}
```

What is wrong with my implementation?

Please see the full source code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This would be in a header file -----------------------------------------------------------------

// Type trait helper to identify iterators --------------------------------------------------------
template<typename T, typename = void> 
struct is_iterator { static constexpr bool value = false; };
template<typename T>
struct is_iterator<T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type, void>::value>::type> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

// The List class ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
class List {
    // Sub class for a Node -----------
    struct Node {
        Node* next{};
        Node* previous{};
        T data{};
        Node(Node* const n, Node* const p, const T& d) : next(n), previous(p), data(d) {}
        Node(Node* const n, Node* const p) : next(n), previous(p) {}
        Node() {}
    };

    // Private list data and functions --------
    size_t numberOfElements{};
    Node* head{};
    void init() { head = new Node(); head->next = head; head->previous = head; numberOfElements = 0; }

public:
    struct iterator;    // Forward declaration

    // Constructor --------------------
    List() { init(); }
    explicit List(const size_t count, const T& value) { init(); insert(begin(), count, value); };
    explicit List(const size_t count) { init(); insert(begin(), count); }
    template <typename Iter>
    List(const Iter& first, const Iter& last) { init(); insert(begin(),first, last); }
    List(const List& other) { init(), insert(begin(), other.begin(), other.end()); };
    List(List&& other) : head(other.head), numberOfElements(other.numberOfElements) { other.init(); }
    List(const std::initializer_list<T>& il) { init(); insert(begin(), il.begin(), il.end()); }
    template <int N> List(const T(&other)[N]) { init(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); }
    template <int N> List(T(&other)[N]) { init(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); }


    // Assignment ---------------------
    List& operator =(const List& other) { clear(); insert(begin(), other.begin(), other.end()); return *this; }
    List& operator =(List&& other) { clear(); head = other.head; numberOfElements = other.numberOfElements; other.init(); return *this; }
    List& operator =(const std::initializer_list<T>& il) { clear(); insert(begin(),il.begin(),il.end()); return *this; }
    template <int N> List& operator =(const T(&other)[N]) { clear(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); return *this; }
    template <int N> List& operator =(T(&other)[N]) { clear(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); return *this;}

    void assign(const size_t count, const T& value) { clear(); insert(begin(), count, value); }
    void assign(const std::initializer_list<T>& il) { clear(); insert(begin(), il.begin(), il.end()); }
    template <typename Iter> void assign(const Iter& first, const Iter& last) { clear(); insert(begin(), first, last);}
    template <int N> void assign(const T(&other)[N]) { clear(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); return *this; }
    template <int N> void assign(T(&other)[N]) { clear(); insert(begin(), std::begin(other), std::end(other)); return *this; }

    // Destructor ---------------------
    ~List() { clear(); }

    // Element Access -----------------
    T& front() { return *begin(); }
    T& back() { return *(--end()); }

    // Iterators ----------------------
    iterator begin() const { return iterator(head->next, head); }
    iterator end() const { return iterator(head, head); }

    // Capacity -----------------------
    size_t size() const { return numberOfElements; }
    bool empty() { return size() == 0; }

    // Modifiers ----------------------
    void clear();

    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition, const T& value);
    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition);
    template <class Iter, std::enable_if_t<is_iterator<Iter>::value, bool> = true>
    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition, const Iter& first, const Iter& last);
    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition, const size_t& count, const T& value);
    iterator insert(const iterator& insertBeforePosition, const std::initializer_list<T>& il);

    iterator erase(const iterator& posToDelete);
    iterator erase(const iterator& first, const iterator& last);


    void push_back(const T& d) { insert(end(), d); }
    void pop_back() { erase(--end()); };

    void push_front(const T& d) { insert(begin(), d); }
    void pop_front() { erase(begin()); };

    void resize(size_t count);
    void resize(size_t count, const T& value);

    void swap(List& other) { std::swap(head, other.head); std::swap(numberOfElements, other.numberOfElements); }

     // Operations --------------------
    void reverse();

    // Non standard inefficient functions --------------------------
    T& operator[](const size_t index) const { return begin()[index]; }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Define iterator capability ---------------------------------------------
    struct iterator {

        // Definitions ----------------
        using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = T*;
        using reference = T&;

        // Data -----------------------
        Node* iter{};
        Node* head{};

        // Constructor ----------------
        iterator(Node*const node, Node* const h) : iter(node), head(h) {};
        iterator() {};

        // Dereferencing --------------
        reference operator*() const { return iter->data; }
        reference operator->() const { return &**this; }

        // Arithmetic operations ------
        iterator operator++() { if (iter != head) iter = iter->next; return *this; }
        iterator operator++(int) { iterator tmp = *this; ++* this; return tmp; }
        iterator operator--() { if (iter != head->next) iter = iter->previous; return *this; }
        iterator operator--(int) { iterator tmp = *this; --* this; return tmp; }

        iterator operator +(const difference_type& n) const {
            iterator temp{ *this };  difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)++temp; else while (k++)--temp; return temp;
        }
        iterator operator +=(const difference_type& n) {
            difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)++* this; else while (k++)--* this; return *this;
        };
        iterator operator -(const difference_type& n) const {
            iterator temp{ *this };  difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)--temp; else while (k++)++temp; return temp;
        }
        iterator operator -=(const difference_type& n) {
            difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)--* this; else while (k++)++* this; return *this;
        };
        // Comparison -----------------
        bool operator ==(const iterator& other) const { return iter == other.iter; };
        bool operator !=(const iterator& other) const { return iter != other.iter; };
        bool operator < (const iterator& other) const { return other.iter - iter < 0; };
        bool operator <= (const iterator& other) const { return other.iter - iter <= 0; };
        bool operator > (const iterator& other) const { return other.iter - iter > 0; };
        bool operator >= (const iterator& other) const { return other.iter - iter >= 0; };

        // Special non standard functions -----------------
        difference_type operator-(const iterator& other) const;
        reference operator[] (const size_t index);
    };
};


// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Implementation of list functions. This would normally go into a TCC file -----------------------

// List class functions ---------------
template <typename T>
void List<T>::clear() {

    for (Node* nextNode{}, * currentNode(head->next); currentNode != head; currentNode = nextNode) {
        nextNode = currentNode->next;
        delete currentNode;
    }
    init();
}
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition, const T& value)
{
    Node* nodeInsertBeforePosition = insertBeforePosition.iter;
    Node* newNode = new Node(nodeInsertBeforePosition, nodeInsertBeforePosition->previous, value);
    nodeInsertBeforePosition->previous = newNode;
    (newNode->previous)->next = newNode;
    ++numberOfElements;
    return iterator(newNode, head);
}
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition)
{
    Node* nodeInsertBeforePosition = insertBeforePosition.iter;
    Node* newNode = new Node(nodeInsertBeforePosition, nodeInsertBeforePosition->previous);
    nodeInsertBeforePosition->previous = newNode;
    (newNode->previous)->next = newNode;
    ++numberOfElements;
    return iterator(newNode, head);
}

template <typename T>
template <class Iter, std::enable_if_t<is_iterator<Iter>::value, bool>>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition, const Iter& first, const Iter& last) {
    iterator result(insertBeforePosition.iter, head);
    if (first != last) {
        result = insert(insertBeforePosition, *first);
        Iter i(first);
        for (++i; i != last; ++i)
            insert(insertBeforePosition, *i);
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition, const size_t& count, const T& value) {

    iterator result(insertBeforePosition.iter, head);
    if (count != 0u) {
        result = insert(insertBeforePosition, value);
        for (size_t i{ 1u }; i < count; ++i)
            insert(insertBeforePosition, value);
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::insert(const List<T>::iterator& insertBeforePosition, const std::initializer_list<T>& il) {
    return insert(insertBeforePosition, il.begin(), il.end());
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::erase(const List<T>::iterator& posToDelete) {

    iterator result = posToDelete;
    ++result;

    Node* nodeToDelete = posToDelete.iter;

    if (nodeToDelete != head) {

        nodeToDelete->previous->next = nodeToDelete->next;
        nodeToDelete->next->previous = nodeToDelete->previous;

        delete nodeToDelete;
        --numberOfElements;
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator List<T>::erase(const List<T>::iterator& first, const List<T>::iterator& last) {
    iterator result{ end() };
    if (first == begin() && last == end())
        clear();
    else {
        while (first != last)
            first = erase(first);
        result = last;
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::resize(size_t count) {
    if (numberOfElements < count)
        for (size_t i{ numberOfElements }; i < count; ++i)
            insert(end());
    else
        while (count--)
            pop_back();
}
template <typename T>
void List<T>::resize(size_t count, const T& value) {
    if (numberOfElements < count)
        for (size_t i{ numberOfElements }; i < count; ++i)
            insert(end(),value);
    else
        while (count--)
            pop_back();
}
template <typename T>
void List<T>::reverse() {
    const Node* oldHead = head;

    for (Node* nptr = head; ; nptr = nptr->previous) {
        std::swap(nptr->next, nptr->previous);
        if (nptr->previous == oldHead) // Previous was the original next
            break;
    }
}

// ------------------------------------
// Iterator functions -----------------
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator::difference_type List<T>::iterator::operator-(const iterator& other) const {

    difference_type result{};
    Node* nptr = head;

    int indexThis{ -1 }, indexOther{ -1 }, index{};

    do {
        nptr = nptr->next;
        if (nptr == iter)
            indexThis = index;
        if (nptr == other.iter)
            indexOther = index;
        ++index;
    } while (nptr != head);

    if (indexThis >= 0 and indexOther >= 0)
        result = indexThis - indexOther;
    return result;
}
template <typename T>
typename List<T>::iterator::reference List<T>::iterator::operator[] (const size_t index) {
    Node* nptr = head->next;
    for (size_t i{}; i < index and nptr != head; ++i, nptr = nptr->next)
        ;
    return nptr->data;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This would be in a cpp file --------------------------------------------------------------------
int main() {

    // std::list works
    std::list<int> list1{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::cout << std::distance(list1.end(), list1.begin()) << '\n';

    // Custom list
    List<int> list2{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    // Delta works
    std::cout << list2.begin() - list2.end() << '\n'; 
    std::cout << list2.end() - list2.begin() << '\n';

    // Hopp Count works
    List<int>::iterator i = list2.end();
    int counter = 0;
    while (i != list2.end()) { 
        ++counter;
        ++i;
    }
    std::cout << counter << '\n';

    // Distance will go into endless loop ****************************
    std::cout << std::distance(list2.end(), list2.begin()) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Please take some to refresh on how to make a [mre], with emphasis on the ***minimal*** part. We don't need all your `List<T>` code to replicate the problem you have.

Comment: As for your problem with your own `List<T>` code, have you tried to debug it? How? Have you used a debugger to see the values of the iterators? Or printed them?

Comment: Why doesn't increment do anything when an iterator points to head?

Comment: By the way, `List<int>::iterator i = list2.end();` and `while (i != list2.end())`? Your loop, if everything worked as expected, shouldn't even iterate once, much less lead to an infinite loop. And from what I can see, it *should* work (both iterators `iter` pointer should be equal so the iterators `!=` operator should return false).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. Trying to debug it? Is this a serious questions to me? Wow. Thank you for the good advice. +1 for this comment

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. With the while loop. I was repeating the implementation of std::distance in the stdlib regarding hopping. And of course it works as expected. And yes. It works. It is just that I can confirm with the debugger expected behaviour. So, is the std implementation not as shown in the source code of the lib?

Comment: @AlanBirtles That is a very good question. I need to debug it. I use a sentinel with a previous and a next pointer, pointed to by head of the List. The previos pointer of the sentinel contains the end of the list and the next pointer of the sentinel contains the pointer to the first element. Maybe I need to compare to head->previous. Let me check . . .

Comment: Assuming you mean that `std::distance(list2.end(), list2.begin())` leads to an infinite loop (which isn't in the code at all, an [mre] should be of the failing code), then your `while` loop doesn't emulate that. To emulate that it should be `while (i != list2.begin())`. And with your list `list2.end() != list2.begin()` is *true* which means the loop iterates, you increase the end iterator and go way out of the list, and keep going.

Comment: How to stop that infinite loop, you might need to look closer at the `std::list<T>::iterator` to see what happens in its comparison operators, and how it differs from your iterator.

Comment: @AlanBirtles. Thank you for this good hint. Indeed I build in a "double" sentinel. Sorry for being blind. By removing the If-Statements from the pre increment and pre decrement operator, I get the correct and same behavior as expected. Can you give your comment as an answer? Then I will accept the answer, otherwise I will delete the question. Thank you very much.

Comment: What would you have expected to happen with a linked list?

Comment: @Galik I would have expected the same behaviour from my implementation as from the `std::list`. As I have written in my question: "Of course I expect UB and indeterminate results" . But I wanted to know, as written in the question, why "std::distance on my implementation goes into an endless loop, while it does not with a std::list". AlanBirtles found the problem. After fixing that, everything works the same.

Comment: *"Of course I expect UB and indeterminate results, but std::distance on my implementation goes into an endless loop, while it does not with a std::list. Why?"* - In exactly what way to you expect UB to manifest itself?

Comment: Jesus Christ. An what level are we discussing here? See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance table 1  and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub, bullet point 5. I expect nothing. It is UB. I wanted to know, why the std::list behaves different (with the same compiler and machine, so implementation dependent) than my implementation, because this may indicate buggy code. Which it did. The compiler output, the assembly code, is well defined and deterministic. And if std::list or my source code results in different behaviour, then this is clear indicator for a potential bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the good comment of AlanBirtles, I found the bug.

I build in (already in the first versions) a wrong additional sentinel for the pre increment and pre decrement operator of the iterator.

The correct version is:

```
iterator operator++() { iter = iter->next; return *this; }
iterator operator--() { iter = iter->previous; return *this; }
```

I originally planned to delete the question, but because of the superb comments, I will leave it. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

This:

```
// Distance will go into endless loop ****************************
std::cout << std::distance(list2.end(), list2.begin()) << '\n';
```

should be:

```
// Distance will go into endless loop ****************************
std::cout << std::distance(list2.begin(), list2.end()) << '\n';
```

What you do here is start from the end and increase the iterator until it reaches the beginning. This is an endless loop

Comment: I know. I do the unit test deliberately with wrong parameters to check the behaviour. And `std::list` shows no endless loop.